# my drive shows size on disk very smaller than its actual size

Tags: ntfs, compression, windows-server, windows-server-2019, size

I have check there is no compression check on ntfs settings but still also 1 TB file shows 60 GB on disk.
How is this possible ?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You have a **[sparse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/sparse-files)** file.  Regions of it which are still empty (not yet written by the program) are not stored on disk at all – instead of pointing to some specific area on disk, they're marked as "unallocated" in NTFS and just automatically appear as 0x00-bytes when read.

Comment: i have also another issue in System volume information /Dedup/chunk this folder take much space of drive and keep going why

Comment: how to off sparsing

Comment: I don't think you can turn it off globally, but what's the point anyway? Usually people want files to occupy less space, not more?

Comment: @Hammadleo91: Making this file non-sparse is possible, but will waste 29 GB of disk space. Why do that?

Comment: okay will not do that but what about dedup taking most space in chunk foolder

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to find which file or files in the folder are sparse:

If there is just one sparse file, it would be the only file whose
size is around 29 GB, so very easy to locate.

If it's more than one file, you may locate the sparse files using this
PowerShell command (once you're positioned to the folder):

```
Get-ChildItem -Attributes SparseFile
```

Reference : PowerShell [Get-ChildItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.4).